# How to get the name of python host application?

Tags: python, qt, interpreter, host

The Python interpreter is embedded in and invoked from many applications these days. I'm working on a PyQt app that can be invoked as standalone app from terminal and also from within Maya, Houdini and Nuke at least.

Is there a way to tell the name of the host application executable from within my running python script? Either directly using just pure python or maybe via PyQt (Maya, Houdini and Nuke all use Qt)?

Comment: Come to think of it, I'm not sure how you'd do this for non-embedded Python.

Comment: Did some looking. Apparently `sys.executable` is what you'd use for non-embedded. Does that give anything reasonable for embedded Python?

Comment: Can't test all the hosts before tomorrow but at least in Houdini sys.executable still returns "/usr/bin/python" on my xubuntu laptop.

Comment: I guess I could just do app specific module imports in a try / except block and see if they work or not. E.g. import maya.cmds as cmds, then see if cmds.about() works. Or import hou, then see if hou.applicationName() works. Would be great to find a generic solution though...

Comment: Just a note, I think sys.executable may still be a generic solution for embedded. On linux, both Maya 2015 and Nuke 9.0 return their main executables. Houdini is the exception in that it will attempt to use the system python (on linux) unless you have set HOUDINI_USE_HFS_PYTHON. More on that here: http://www.sidefx.com/docs/houdini15.0/hom/_index#which-python

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution that works pretty well in all of our DCC applications:

```py
import sys

if 'hou' in sys.modules:
    # Houdini
    pass
elif 'maya' in sys.modules:
    # Maya
    pass
elif 'Katana' in sys.modules:
    # Katana
    pass
elif 'nuke' in sys.modules:
    # Nuke
    pass
else:
    # Unknown host application or standalone Python
    pass
```